# Genie show involving Magic and such

Tags: story-identification

Can anyone remember the name of a fantasy-comedy show where a so-called "Genie" with brown possibly curly hair and a mustache lives with a family? I remember this one episode where this "Genie" turned a grumpy, mean coach back into a kid and the family's football son into an adult to teach him a lesson temporarily, much to the mother's protest and objection when she enters the room.

I remember he lived with a mom, dad, a son, and possibly a daughter. And he was an adult with brown curly hair and a mustache.

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GenieInABottle

Comment: I was talking about a live action fantasy-comedy show involving such a person

Comment: If you follow the link, there's lots to choose from.

Comment: Neither of them match my description

Comment: Probably *Genie in the House*, from the page Valorum has linked for you?  Closest fit on there. If it's not... well, plenty of possibilities to check out.

Comment: Nah. I thought the same thing too but the one I remember was where he lived with a mom, dad, a son, and possibly a daughter. And he was an adult with brown curly hair and a mustache. My sister used to refer him as a Genie but I doubt it. See if you can find a link that leads to a magic man instead.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like the show [You Wish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_Wish_(TV_series)). See the photo below for the Genie and the family.

I can't find the exact episode you are referring to, but this [episode guide](http://epguides.com/YouWish/guide.shtml) lists the guest role of football player in episode 10, "Welcome to the Dollhouse".

[image: Genie and family]